# docker-compose won't open /bin/bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have set-up a docker-compose file for rails following the tutorial from [evilmartians](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/ruby-on-whales-docker-for-ruby-rails-development) like this.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app: &app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./.dockerdev/Dockerfile
      args:
        RUBY_VERSION: '2.6.5'
        MYSQL_MAJOR: '14'
        NODE_MAJOR: '11'
        YARN_VERSION: '1.16.0'
        BUNDLER_VERSION: '2.1.4'
    image: myapp-dev:1.2.0
    tmpfs:
        - /tmp

  backend: &backend
    <<: *app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes: 
      - .:/app:cached
      - rails_cache:/app/tmp/cache
      - bundle:/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - packs:/app/public/packs
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-development}
      - DB_USERNAME=root
      - DB_DATABASE=myapp_development
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_HOST=mysql
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/
      - BOOTSNAP_CACHE_DIR=/usr/local/bundle/_bootsnap
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=webpacker
      - WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
      - HISTFILE=/app/log/.bash_history
      - EDITOR=vi
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
      - dynamodb
      - webpacker

  runner:
    <<: *backend
    command: ["/bin/bash"]
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
      - '3002:3002'

  rails:
    <<: *backend
    command: ["./.dockerdev/scripts/start_rails.sh"]
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
    ports:
      - 6379

  webpacker:
    <<: *app
    command: ["./.dockerdev/scripts/start_webpack_dev.sh"]
    ports:
      - '3035:3035'
    volumes:
      - .:/app:cached
      - bundle:/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - packs:/app/public/packs
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-development}
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-development}
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0

  dynamodb:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

volumes:
  mysql:
  redis:
  bundle:
  node_modules:
  rails_cache:
  packs:
```

However, when I run `docker-compose up runner` it is always stuck at `Attaching to myapp_runner_1`.

When I get into the container from another bash window/tab with `docker exec -it myapp_runner_1 /bin/bash` and run `ps -Al` I can see that there is another bash process running. It is just that I can't seem to run anything in the original window/tab.

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `runner` container supposed to do?  How do you interact with it?  Does it need to be an always-on long-running process?  (`docker-compose run backend bash` can get you a temporary container in the unusual event you do need an interactive shell to debug your container setup.)

Comment: According to the article, it's not so different from what you mentioned, except it is in a different container. I understand I can run the command you mentioned, I am simply wondering why I am stuck at `Attaching to ...` and how to solve it.

Comment: You should be able to just delete that block with no ill effect.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might help:

```
  runner:
    <<: *backend
    command: ["/bin/bash"]
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
      - '3002:3002'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Comment: Since `backend` itself already contains those `stdin_open` and `tty` attributes it doesn't really help.